# Reuse rsync --dry-run output to speed up the actual transfer later on

Tags: text-processing, terminal, rsync

I usually do `rsync -n` before doing an actual `rsync`. The thing is, how could I automate the second run to reuse exactly the list generated with `--dry-run`?

I mean, if I run `rsync -n` then I get a simulation of what `rsync` would do, my idea would be to take that output, process it then somehow make `rsync` only `--include-from` that output, so the full list has to be calculated only once.

If this doesn't even make sense, please, let me know.

By the way, I tend to use `rsync -hva --progress --stats --delete --exclude-from "$EXCLUDEFILE"`. If you also have a suggestion on what options would you use, please, let me know. I'm trying to duplicate the contents of an external hard drive (that only contains images, videos and documents) to another external hard drive.

Comment: You could try redirecting the output from the `--dry-run` command into a file (e.g., `rsync --dry-run -avz SOURCE DEST > include.txt`), removing all lines that aren't files/paths from include.txt, and running `rsync --include-from include.txt`.

Comment: That last command should be `rsync --include-from include.txt --exclude=* SOURCE DEST`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19296415/1765910 for details.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but I don't know how to actually do that (plus I would like the approval from someone that actually knows what (s)he's doing). I just use `rsync` but don't know anything from shell scripts / bash…

Answer (score 36):

It is certainly possible to use the file list generated during a dry run as an include file. Ideally, however, the extra lines at the top and bottom of the dry-run output should be deleted.

Example output:

```
sending incremental file list
[LIST OF FILES]

sent 226 bytes  received 34 bytes  520.00 bytes/sec
total size is 648,373,274  speedup is 2,493,743.36 (DRY RUN)
```

To remove these lines, pipe the `rsync` output into `head` and into `tail`. Then, save the processed output to an include file:

`rsync --dry-run -avz source/ destination/ | head --lines=-3 | tail --lines=+3 > include.txt`

Finally, tell `rsync` to use the generated include file (adding additional options as desired):

`rsync --include-from=include.txt --exclude=* source/ dest/`

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't cope with files that should be deleted. And is that method of `tail`/`head` robust enough to ensure having only the list of files?

Comment: Adding `--delete` causes files deleted from the source directories to be deleted from the destination directories as well, at least on the computer I tried it on. You can leave out the `tail`/`head` part entirely. `rsync` interprets each line in the include file as a file name and simply ignores non-existing files, so nothing will happen if you keep the extra lines (unless you happen to have files named "sending incremental file list", etc., in which case these files will be copied as well).

Comment: You also may use `| sed '1d;/^$/,$d` as an alternative for `| head --lines=-3 | tail --lines=+3 `. In case you want to add more filtering with sed it would be one command, not three.

Comment: I am not sure this would make any sense as rsync works on a server / client base and the server will have to calculate the files / chunks to be transmitted anyway, be it all in one go or one after another. 

Would be nice to have an opinion about this from somebody with more knowledge than my humble self ;)